# How to retrieve values from a Python QuerySet?

Tags: python

There are questions similar to this, however, I'm finding those particular posts somewhat difficult to follow.

I have a QuerySet of the type:

```
chembl_webresource_client.query_set.QuerySet
```

When I print the QuerySet object I see the following:

*[{'atc_classifications': [], 'availability_type': 1, 'biotherapeutic': None, 'black_box_warning': 1, 'chebi_par_id': 8466, 'chirality': 0, 'cross_references': [{'xref_id': 'propafenone%20hydrochloride', 'xref_name': 'propafenone hydrochloride', 'xref_src': 'DailyMed'}, {'xref_id': '26747617', 'xref_name': 'SID: 26747617', 'xref_src': 'PubChem'}, {'xref_id': '26747618', 'xref_name': 'SID: 26747618', 'xref_src': 'PubChem'}, {'xref_id': '50106779', 'xref_name': 'SID: 50106779', 'xref_src': 'PubChem'}, {'xref_id': '50106780', 'xref_name': 'SID: 50106780', 'xref_src': 'PubChem'}, {'xref_id': '50106781', 'xref_name': 'SID: 50106781', 'xref_src': 'PubChem'}, {'xref_id': '56422489', 'xref_name': 'SID: 56422489', 'xref_src': 'PubChem'}, {'xref_id': '855997', 'xref_name': 'SID: 855997', 'xref_src': 'PubChem'}], 'dosed_ingredient': True, 'first_approval': 1989, 'first_in_class': 0, 'helm_notation': None, 'indication_class': 'Cardiac Depressant (anti-arrhythmic)', 'inorganic_flag': 0, 'max_phase': 4, **'molecule_chembl_id': 'CHEMBL1201063'**,**...[TRUNCATED]***

**QUESTION**

How do I pull out the String representation of **molecule_chembl_id** (towards the end of the truncated screen dump)?

This is not django related. The package isn't installed on my machine. This is a QuerySet object from the ChEMBL chembl_webresource_client package.

Please note: This question strikes me as relatively simple. However, I am finding similar examples and posts difficult to follow. I would appreciate a mention of each data type, that way I can learn which part of a package is being used. For example, to me, a return variable of `res` means absolutely nothing, whereas something like `res_QuerySet` is instantly recognisable for what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I understand your question, it seems to work like a dictionary (actually dictionaries in a list).
Is this what you mean?

```
# Retrieving queryset.
from chembl_webresource_client.new_client import new_client
molecule = new_client.molecule
res_QuerySet = molecule.search('iron')

# Printing value.
res_QuerySet[0]["molecule_chembl_id"]
>>>'CHEMBL1200823'

# Getting multiple.
for hit in res_QuerySet:
    print(hit['molecule_chembl_id'])
>>>CHEMBL1200823
>>>CHEMBL1201544
>>>CHEMBL2447909
>>>(etc)
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll give this a try. I have edited my post above so the question is easily identifiable. I had no idea it worked like a dictionary.

Comment: I'll let you know as soon as I've tried. I'm a bit tied up with other work at this exact moment.